# Kotlin Json Parse

Tags: json, kotlin, webapi

Why does my Json parse fail with following error?

JSON from Web API

```
[{"CUSTJOBID":1,"JOBDT":"2020-11-18T00:00:00","JobFromAdd":"TT4 6PX","JobToAdd":"GH8 7HH"}]
```

KOTLIN CODE to PASRSE

```
val jsonarray = JSONArray(response.toString())
```

> App error of type `java.lang.String` cannot be converted to JSONArray

Comment: The JSON that you posted is correct for JSONArray but can you show the whole response JSON?

Comment: HI Hayssam, when i use post man it comes as this "[{\"CUSTJOBID\":1,\"JOBDT\":\"2020-11-18T00:00:00\",\"JobFromAdd\":\"ST4 6PX\",\"JobToAdd\":\"B78 3HH\"}]"    and error says Caused by: org.json.JSONException: Value [{"CUSTJOBID":1,"JOBDT":"2020-11-18T00:00:00","JobFromAdd":"ST4 6PX","JobToAdd":"B78 3HH"},{"CUSTJOBID":1,"JOBDT":"2020-11-18T00:00:00","JobFromAdd":"ST4 6PX","JobToAdd":"B78 3HH"}] of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray

Comment: this is the whole json, as im converting a data table to json using a vb.net function on web api

Comment: If the opening and closing quotes `"[...]"` are included as part of the response that could be it

Comment: var strres ="[{\"CUSTJOBID\":1,\"JOBDT\":\"2020-11-18T00:00:00\",\"JobFromAdd\":\"TT4 6PX\",\"JobToAdd\":\"GH8 7HH\"}]" works and no errors going to Array but if i use api response and take out first and last charactors like var strres =response.toString()
                        strres =strres.toString().substring(1, response.length-1)
                        Log.e("Response", strres)
                        val jsonarray = JSONArray(strres), it throws Caused by: org.json.JSONException: Expected literal value at character 2 of [{\"CUSTJOBID\":1,\"JOBDT

Comment: How can i use api response to format like static variable i used above, i have tried taking out first and last charactors but failed with Caused by: org.json.JSONException: Expected literal value at character 2 of [{\"CUSTJOBID\":1,\"JOBDT